# String hidden inside .s assembly source code

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

I've been really stuck with a challenge at our "hacking" class. A string (password) needs to be found, and the only file provided is a .s assembly file.

Based on my extremely small knowledge of assembly, I compiled the file with `gcc -S Program.s`, with an `a.out`executable file being output. I tried to run the file with `./a.out` in Mac Terminal, to no success — after pressing enter at the end of the command, cursor just jumps to a new line with nothing in stdout, and `echo $?` returns `0`.

At the end of the assembly file, there's a `.asciz  "zja4heit5k7"`, so I figured it might be the correct string, but to no success.

I would be eternally thankful if anyone can provide **any steps** to help me solve the problem.

```
Program.s
```

.

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .macosx_version_min 10, 13
    .globl  _r
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_r:                                     ## @r
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Lcfi0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Lcfi1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Lcfi2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -12(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -12(%rbp)
LBB0_1:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movb    %al, %cl
    cmpq    $0, -8(%rbp)
    movb    %cl, -13(%rbp)          ## 1-byte Spill
    je  LBB0_3
## BB#2:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movslq  -12(%rbp), %rcx
    movsbl  (%rax,%rcx), %edx
    cmpl    $0, %edx
    setne   %sil
    movb    %sil, -13(%rbp)         ## 1-byte Spill
LBB0_3:                                 ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movb    -13(%rbp), %al          ## 1-byte Reload
    testb   $1, %al
    jne LBB0_4
    jmp LBB0_9
LBB0_4:                                 ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movslq  -12(%rbp), %rcx
    movsbl  (%rax,%rcx), %edx
    cmpl    $97, %edx
    jl  LBB0_7
## BB#5:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movslq  -12(%rbp), %rcx
    movsbl  (%rax,%rcx), %edx
    addl    $13, %edx
    cmpl    $122, %edx
    jg  LBB0_7
## BB#6:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movslq  -12(%rbp), %rcx
    movsbl  (%rax,%rcx), %edx
    addl    $13, %edx
    movb    %dl, %sil
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movslq  -12(%rbp), %rcx
    movb    %sil, (%rax,%rcx)
LBB0_7:                                 ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    jmp LBB0_8
LBB0_8:                                 ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)
    jmp LBB0_1
LBB0_9:
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .globl  _main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Lcfi3:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Lcfi4:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Lcfi5:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    leaq    _an(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    callq   _r
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .section    __DATA,__data
    .globl  _an                     ## @an
_an:
    .asciz  "zja4heit5k7"


.subsections_via_symbols
```

Comment: That should probably be `gcc Program.s` (no `-S`). You use `-S` if you want to create a `.s` file (e.g. from a `.c` file).

Comment: `gcc -S foo.S` doesn't create `a.out`.  Use `ls -l` to check the timestamp and see what `a.out` you actually ran.  Also, run `gdb ./a.out` so you can set a breakpoint and single-step through it.

Comment: Did you consider asking your teacher?

Comment: @melpomene just tried the command without -S, still the output `a.out` doesn't return anything after being executed

Comment: So now you get to learn assembly code and how to single-step through code in a debugger.

Comment: it have to return anything, at least zero. not on the stdout, but check `echo $?`

Comment: @sivizius checked `echo $?`, yes, it returns 0, I will edit the question now

Comment: @RafaelSofi-Zadeh With `-S`, the compiler does not actually generate a binary.  So at least now you have the right binary to test.